# Usage of it and ommission of object

Tags: pronouns, objects

> Temperatures  on  the  moon  are  quite  extreme,  ranging  from  110°C  to  -  173°C.  This  occurs because  there  is  no  atmosphere  to  filter  sun’s  rays  when  **it**  is  shining  and  then  to  **blanket**  in  warm  air when  the  sun  goes  down.

In this paragraph, what does 'it' refer to, the moon, the sun or the meaningless subject for weather?
What is the object of "blanket", the sun's rays or the moon?

Answer (score 1):

The *it* refers to the sun or the sun's rays. Contextually this is apparent as the *sun's rays* immediately precede the use of *it* and the sun is the most likely subject to shine. This makes sense if you substitute in *sun* or *sun's rays* into the sentence.

> ..no atmosphere to filter sun's rays when the **sun** is shining...
>
> ..no atmosphere to filter sun's rays when the **sun's rays** are shining...

The object *blanket* is referring to can be a bit harder to parse. The object is **atmosphere**, which I will demonstrate by reducing the sentence down as such:

> This occurs because there is no atmosphere to filter [X] and then to blanket [Y].

The [X] is part of describing the condition of the filtering. *Blanket* is a separate term. You can verify this by removing the "filter" clause and checking the resulting sentence.

> This occurs because there is no atmosphere to blanket in warm air when the sun goes down.